# Which data type and length is most suitable for an auto increment id column in database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net, auto-increment

I am developing a website and using SQL Server as my database. I have a lot of entries every day and the id is auto incremented.

Should I use `INT` or `BIGINT`, or is there another suitable datatype?

Comment: How much is "a lot"? INT is fine if you're not expecting more than 2^31-1 entries.

Comment: Do a little [research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql) and make your own informed decision.

Comment: View it this way. Let's say you have 10,000 entries per day, multiply that by 365 that's 3,650,000 entries per year. Multiply that 100 for 100 years, that would be 365,000,000. SQL Server's int has a maximum value of 2,147,483,647. And I doubt that your app will still be running after a hundred years :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a type of `INT`, starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases.

If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert a row **every second** of every minute of every hour of every day, then you need **66.5 years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

With `BIGINT`, you get roughly **922 quadrillion** (922 with 15 zeros - 9'220'000 billions) - enough for you??

If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert one thousand rows every second, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Read more about it (with all the options there are) in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

INT if you will insert less than 2,147,483,648 records , BIGINT if you will insert more